# How to bind a xml element into an object member variable?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, moxy

I'm trying to unmarshal an xml to an object using moxy.Below is the sample of the xml.

```
<root>
    <name>
        <firstname>value</firstname>
    </name> 
    <address>value of address</address>
</root>
```

And below is the class I'm trying to map.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

public class Response {
  @XmlPath("name/firstname/text()")
  String name;
  Address address;
}

class Address {
  String addressline;
}
```

Now how do I get the values of the address tag in XML and bind it to the addressline variable of class Address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `@XmlValue` annotation on the `addressline` property.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Address {
    @XmlValue
    String addressline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.It was really helpful.But what if my Address class contains another variable called addresslinetwo and I want to map it to an element in the XML which has <root> as parent.To be exact that is my actual problem.

Comment: @cgeek - You could annotate the `address` property with `@XmlPath(".")`.

Comment: Using Jackson 2 with Jersey, I had to replace '@XmlValue' annotation by Jackson's '@JsonValue' annotation to make it work

Answer (score 0):

this is an answer for a similar (but not *exactly the* same) question that was linked here:

- [How can I encourage JAXB to read XmlElement content string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006503/how-can-i-encourage-jaxb-to-read-xmlelement-content-string)

The solution for our issue relates to this question as well.  For the issue above, the short answer ([as noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006503/how-can-i-encourage-jaxb-to-read-xmlelement-content-string) *there*) is to use  @**XmlValue** attribute with the getMessageText(),  not @XmlElement.  I had already use 'XmlValue', and it still didn't work, so I reverted to XmlElement.

XmlValue wasn't the whole solution in [that case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006503/how-can-i-encourage-jaxb-to-read-xmlelement-content-string).  We also found that we need:

- @**XmlAccessorType**( XmlAccessType.NONE )

Apparently because of other stuff in the class.  Evidentially JABX tries to match every get/set property with XML and apparently it got confused and can't or won't process my XmlValue if there are non-XML POJO properties (I deduce).

```
  @XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.NONE )
  @XmlRootElement(name = "announcement")
  public class Announcement
  {
      ... 

      @XmlValue
      public  String getMessageText(){
          return this.messageText;
      }
  }
```

Lesson learned.  If your JAXB doesn't do what you think it ought to do, *I have confused it*.  Thanks for the help, knowing what is needed to do, let us find what else we needed too.