# How can I encourage JAXB to read XmlElement content string?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm not getting my "announcements" when I try to parse messages like these:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <message messageType="SUBSCRIBER" messageName="ANNOUNCEMENT">
     <announcement time="12:30">
         Lunchtime!
     </announcement>
     <announcement time="32:00">
         Good night ...
     </announcement>
     <errorText>Phone number missing, subscriber: Dick</errorText>
 </message>
```

The JAXB Java class seemed pretty straightforward.  And is based on similar messages that work.  In this case the difference seems to be that I can have two different types of nested element (XmlElement) in the main  block.

The code below actually parses the XML but it doesn't call the Announcement.**setMessageText**()  method.  Whereas I can see that the time attribute is set from the XML and I have an array size=2 for announcements, it reads and sets the single errorText XmlElement.  *Btw*, I also removed the  tag from the code and XML -- Not change in treatment of my  messageText.  Ideas welcome!

```
 @XmlRootElement(name = "message")
 public class AnnouncementMessage 
 { 
      @XmlAttribute
      public String getMessageName(){
        return this.messageName;
      }
      public void   setMessageName( String name ){
        this.messageName = name;
      }

      @XmlAttribute
      public String getMessageType(){
          return messageType;
      }
      public void  setMessageType( String newMessageType ){
          this.messageType = newMessageType;
     }

      @XmlElement(name = "errorText")
      public String getErrorText(){
          return errorText;
      }
      public void setErrorText( String newMsg ){
          this.errorText = newMsg;
      }

     private     List<Announcement>  announcements   = new ArrayList<>();

  @XmlElement(name = "announcement")
  public List<Announcement> getAnnouncements(){
        return this.announcements;
  }
  public void setAnnouncements( List<Announcement> newAnnouncements ){
        this.announcements = newAnnouncements;
     }
 }
```

And the Announcement class:

```
 @XmlRootElement(name = "announcement")
 public class Announcement 
 {

     private     String  messageText = "";
     private     String  time        = "12:00";

     XmlAttribute(name ="time")
     public  String  getTime(){
         return this.time;
     }
     public  void    setTime( String newMsg ){
         this.messageText = time;
     }

     @XmlElement(name="announcement")
     public  String  getMessageText(){
         return this.messageText;
     }
     public  void    setMessageText( String newMsg ){
         this.messageText = newMsg;
     }

     Announcement(){
     }
 }
```

Using the name parameter in the for the XmlElement seem to make no difference.  My *thanks in advance*.

Comment: @Blaise Dougan .. I don't think this is a duplicate.  There is a different XML packet that work per the: [How to bind a xml-element-into an object member variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053083/how-to-bind-a-xml-element-into-an-object-member-variable) question.  That is one that works.  This class should be the same, but it isn't.  I parses the attributes, and not the XmlValue.

Comment: @BlaiseDougan Agree with OP that this is not a duplicate. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`@XmlValue`](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/jaxb20-pr/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlValue.html) annotation for the message text:

```
@XmlValue
public  String getMessageText(){
    return this.messageText;
}
```

Additionally, as noted in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25007168/3558960) by OP, an `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` is needed on the `Announcement` class if it contains getter/setter pairs that are not mapped to/from XML and don't have an `@XmlTransient` annotation.

Comment: Yes, this was part of the answer.  The more complete solution has been added to the earlier question:  [How to bind a xml-element-into an object member variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053083/how-to-bind-a-xml-element-into-an-object-member-variable) question.  This problem _interesting_ ... lol

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the feedback. I'll update my answer.